# Why is @instance variable out of scope inside of methods inside an object

Tags: ruby, scope

Why is my @instance variable 'name' out of scope inside of methods inside an object

```
class Name

  @name = 'bob  

  puts @name

  def foo
     @name
  end   

end


new = Name.new
p new.foo
```

The above code returns

> bob
>
> nil

Comment: `@name` in `@name = 'bob'` is a *class instance variable*, belonging to `Name`. The other `@name` is an *instance variable*, belonging to the instance `new`. They are as different as night and day, and co-exist just fine. Try adding `def initialize; @name = 'sue'; end`. Then `name = Name.new; name.foo #=> 'sue'`, but `Name.instance_variable_get(:@name) #=> 'bob'`. Note `Name.instance_variables #=> [:@name]; name.instance_variables #=> [:@name]`, but those are different variables.

Comment: Note that poor `'bob` is missing his closing quote. Also, as most classes have a class method `new`, using `new` as your own local variable can be confusing. It's best to avoid giving variables names that are the names of Ruby methods.

Comment: This is an example where the duplicate question is better than the original (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366565/what-to-do-when-a-question-marked-as-a-duplicate-is-better-than-the-original-que) - the exampe is simpler. Ideally the "marked duplicate" direction should be reversed imo.